# Sequence of Functions Converging to 0

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

I encountered this question in a textbook. While I understand the intuition behind it I am not sure how to formally prove it.

Define the sequence of functions $(g_n)$ on $[0,1]$ to be $$g_{k,n}(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \left[\dfrac{k}n, \dfrac{k+1}n\right]\\ 0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}$$
where $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

Prove the following statements:

1) $g_n \to 0$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm.

2) $g_n(x)$ doesn't converge to $0$ at any point in $[0,1]$.

3) There is a subsequence of $(g_n)$ that converges pointwise to $0$.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence is given by
$$f_{k,n}(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \left[\dfrac{k}n, \dfrac{k+1}n\right]\\ 0 & \text{ else}\end{cases}$$
where $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$.

$1$). Note that $$\int_0^1 \vert f_{k,n} \vert^2 d \mu = \mu\left( \left[\dfrac{k}n, \dfrac{k+1}n\right]\right) = \dfrac1n \to 0 \text{ as }n \to \infty$$

$2$). Consider any $x \in [0,1]$. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $x \in \left[\dfrac{k}n, \dfrac{k+1}n \right]$ for some $k = k_x(n)$. (Why?)

$3$). Consider the subsequence $f_{m,n}(x)$, where $m$ is a fixed number in $\{1,2,\ldots,n-2\}$.

**EDIT**

Adding more details to $2$ and $3$.

$2$). Choose $k_x(n) = \left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor$. By definition, we have $\left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor \leq nx \leq \left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor+1$. Hence, we get that$$\dfrac{\left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor}n \leq x \leq \dfrac{\left \lfloor nx\right \rfloor+1}n$$Hence, for a fixed $x$, if we look at the subsequence, $h_n(x) = f_{k_n(x),n}(x)$, we have $h_n(x) = 1$ for all $n$. Hence, we have subsequence of $f_{k,n}(x)$ converging to $1$.

$3$). Consider the sequence $$h_n(x) = f_{1,n}(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \left[\dfrac1n, \dfrac2n \right]\\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$$ Note that clearly $h_n(0) = 0$, since $0 < \dfrac1n$ for all $n$. Now for any other $x$, note that there exists a $N$ such that $\dfrac2N < x$. Beyond this $N$, for the given $x$, we have $h_n(x) = 0$ for all $n \geq N$. Hence, for any fixed point $x$, we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding number 2. What does k(n) mean?

Comment: @Tom Note that given any $n$, any $x \in [0,1]$ falls in an interval of the form $$\left[\dfrac{\lfloor nx \rfloor}n,\dfrac{\lfloor nx \rfloor+1}n\right]$$ Hence, $k=k_x(n) = \lfloor nx \rfloor$. The notation is to indicate that $k$ depends on both $x$ and $n$. Hence, $k_x(n)$.

Comment: Regarding (3), isn't $f_{n-1,n}(1) = 1$ for all $n$? I think you want the sequence of indicator functions of $[\tfrac1n,\tfrac2n]$ instead. Then the sequence of values will be eventually constant at any $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: @kahen would you mind explaining how $1/n$ and $2/n$ are subsequences of $g_n$? I certainly understand that these both converge to 0, but I don't quite see where they're coming from. Thank you.

Comment: @Tom $\tfrac1n$ and $\tfrac2n$ are *not* subsequences of $g_n$. But for any $k \in \mathbb N$ there is an index $\ell_k$ such that $g_{\ell_k}$ is the indicator function of $[\tfrac1k,\tfrac2k]$.

Comment: @kahen Thanks. Have updated it now. Yes. Any fixed $m$ other than $0$ or $n-1$ would do the job.

Comment: @user17762 I'm still having some difficulty with parts 2 and 3. For part 2, why must x fall in that interval, and how does that prove $g_n(x)$ doesn't converge to 0? For part 3, I'm having trouble understanding what the subsequence is. Thank you

Comment: @Tom Is it clear that $x$ lies in the interval in my first comment?

Comment: @user17762 after reading it again I understand that any x lies in that interval, so this implies that the sequence takes the value of 1 so we can't have pointwise convergence to 0. I believe then that my only question is regarding part 3.

Comment: @Tom Have elaborated on part $2$ and $3$ in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1) What is $\lVert g_n\rVert_2$?

2) Show that for any $x$, $g_n(x)=0$ infinitely often and  $g_n(x)=1$ infinitely often.

3) Note that $\frac1n\to 0 $ and $\frac2n\to 0$

Comment: Two posts differing by $1$ second!